# How do I split a string into two separate columns in Standard SQL (Google BigQuery)?

Tags: sql, split, google-bigquery

I have a column that contains measurements in terms of length and width. Each entry in this column is written in the form lxw. I need to separate this column into two separate columns with one being length and the other being width. Please see below:

This is my original column called "size":

| size |
| --- |
| 930x570 |
| 1460x700 |
| 4x7 |

I want to turn "size" into columns "length" and "width" as follows:

| length | width |
| --- | --- |
| 930 | 570 |
| 1460 | 700 |
| 4 | 7 |

Comment: have you tried something?! show us! maybe this hint (SPLIT) will help you to do so. you have it in title of your question and as a tag!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use below

```
select 
  split(size, 'x')[offset(0)] as length,
  split(size, 'x')[offset(1)] as width
from your_table
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split()`:

```
select t.*,
       split(size, 'x')[ordinal(1)] as length,
       split(size, 'x')[ordinal(2)] as width
from t;
```